# Javascript and HTML input scanning and CSS changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I'm trying to create an `<input>` that on "unfocus or deselect" asks a function if the data entered inside is valid(Like a password checker) If it is i want it to then change the colour of the inputs background depending on the validity of the response

```
Width of walls in meters: <input size="40" placeholder="Please enter a number between 1 and 25" type="number" onkeypress="ifTwo();" name="wallWidthInput"><br>  <!-- Input Field for wallWidthInput-->


var wallWidthElem = document.getElementsByName("wallWidthInput")[0];    //Finds wallWidthInput, sets wallWidthElem
var wallWidth = parseFloat(wallWidthElem.value)         //converts wallWidthElem into a float, sets wallWidth

function ifTwo(){

    if (1<=wallWidth && wallWidth<=25) {}               //if the wallWidth is between 1 and 25, do nothing. If not alert the user!
    else{document.getElementsByName("numberOfWallsInput").style.background="red"; wallWidth=1;}}
```

Comment: How much code have you write to achieve it? Can you post it?

Comment: Your google query words for today will be "html" "css" "form" "input" "field" "validation" and "how to'

Comment: Its very common thing just google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two css classes as follow:

```
.ff {background-color:yellow;}
.noff {background-color: red;}
```

script is like:

```
$(function(){

 var myinput=$("wallWidthInput");
  function checkPassword(){
           //check your rules here
  }
  myinput.on('focusout',function(){ 
        if(!checkPassword()){
            myinput.toggleClasscss("ff");
        }else{myinput.toggleClass("noff");}
  });
  myinput.on('focus',function(){ 
        myinput.toggleClasscss("ff"); // or any default style
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it with plain JavaScript you could do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateWidth(input){ //we'll get the input element as paramter
    var wallWidth = parseFloat(input.value); //read the value each time
    if (1<=wallWidth && wallWidth<=25){
        input.style.background=""; //you'll probably want to reset the background
    } else {
        input.style.background="red"; 
        input.value=1;
    }
}
</script>

Width of walls in meters:
<input size="40" placeholder="Please enter a number between 1 and 25" type="number" onchange="validateWidth(this);" name="wallWidthInput"><br>
```

I've chosen to trigger the validation onchange, because then we validate even if someone uses the small arrows.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      function checkPassword(){
               //your logic return true or false based on condition
      }
      $(":input[name='pwd']").on('focusout',function(){ // When losing focus
            if(!checkPassword()){
                $(this).css('background',somecolorCode);
            }else{$(this).css('background','#ffffff');}
      });
      $(":input[name='pwd']").on('focus',function(){ // When focus
            $(this).css('background','#333');
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is that jQuery> Yeah I'm scared of jQuery

Comment: yah its jQuery.If u r scared of jQuery then better be friend of this cos javaScript is horrible :)

Comment: JavaScript is horrible for everything dom manipulation, cross browser support,code complexity.You check AJAX code of jQuery and simple javascript you will find the simplicity of jQuery

Comment: Since this question isn't tagged with jQuery, you shouldn't provide a jQuery-only answer. Please provide an alternative solution that doesn't rely on any libraries. Also, you haven't provided any **explanation** with your code and didn't even mention that you are using jQuery (in the answer).